# Does adding the Traffic layer to our Google maps invoke an additional cost?

Tags: google-maps

The company I work has a license for commercial use of Google Maps in our products.

Does adding the Google Map Traffic layer for our customers involve an additional cost?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can address this question directly to Google Maps support team via https://console.developers.google.com/google/maps-apis/support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding layers to a Google map does not have an additional cost. It would be mentioned in Google's [billing documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing) or [pricing sheet](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet) otherwise. Google also states the following in the linked billing doc:

> User interactions with the map, such as panning, zooming, or switching
>   map layers, do not generate additional map loads.

Hope this helps!